# How to create an object array for a country list using html dom?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, select

Got stuck with this one for awhile now. Any help would be appreciated.

I am making a select element with country options for my website. I have a javascript file with 2-object array country list (I can't specify the options in html file, only use this js file):

```
var country_list = [
{"country_code": "CA", "country_name": "Canada"},
{"country_code": "UK", "country_name": "United Kingdom"},
{"country_code": "AU", "country_name": "Australia"},
{"country_code": "NZ", "country_name": "New Zealand"} ];
```

And then here is my html file:

```
<form name="form1">    
Country <select value="country_code" onclick="select_country()"></select>
</form>
```

Country names have to be showed on the dropdown list, while the values for the options will be 2-letter country codes. Plus, Australia has to be selected by default.

This is what I have been up to so far:

```
function select_country(){
var select = document.form1.createElement("SELECT");
select.setAttribute("id","mySelect");
document.form1.body.appendChild(select);
var option = document.form1.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("value", "Canada");
var text = document.createTextNode("CAN");
option.appendChild(text);
document.form1.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: aside: I wouldn't recommend using pure DOM api for building your client side js.  Use jquery or equivalent

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o4nqonk2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with vanilla js:

```
var selectElem = document.createElement("select");
for (var i = 0; i < country_list.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = country_list[i].country_name;
    option.value = country_list[i].country_code;

    if (option.text == "Australia") option.selected = true; //default option
    selectElem.appendChild(option);
}

document.form1.body.appendChild(selectElem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i=0; i <=country_list.length; i++){
    var select = document.form1.createElement("SELECT");
    select.setAttribute("id","mySelect"+i);
    document.form1.body.appendChild(select);
    var option = document.form1.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", country_list[i].country_name);
    var text = document.createTextNode(country_list[i].country_code);
    option.appendChild(text);
    document.form1.getElementById("mySelect"+i).appendChild(option);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use jQuery to do it:

```
var country_list = [{
    "country_code": "CA",
    "country_name": "Canada"
}, {
    "country_code": "UK",
    "country_name": "United Kingdom"
}, {
    "country_code": "AU",
    "country_name": "Australia"
}, {
    "country_code": "NZ",
    "country_name": "New Zealand"
}]
.forEach(function(e){
    $("<option value='"+ e.country_code+"'>"+e.country_name+"</option>")
    .appendTo("select");
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwdqh8sa/)